# Algoritmo que checa se a soma de qualquer dois itens de um array ordenado é igual a um número produzindo resultados errados

Tags: javascript, algoritmo

Esse algoritmo pairSum deve achar se a soma de qualquer dois itens de um array *arr* ordenado é igual a um dado número *target*:

```
    function pairSum(arr, target){

    for (var i=0; i<arr.length;){

        for (var j = arr.length-1; j>i;){

            if (i=j) {return false} else {

                if (arr[i] + arr[j] === target){ //we have our case

                    return true;

                } else if (arr[i]+arr[j] < target) { //we don't have our case, but we know the last item (right index = j) needs to stay on the calculation, so we only change i

                    i++;

                } else {

                    j--; //we still don't have our case, but we know the last item (right index = j) is not part of the solution, so we skip it to the left, and we keep the left item (index = i)

                }
           }; 
        };

    };
    return false;

};

//invocation // current result // desired result
console.log( pairSum( [3,4,6,8,9,11], 14) ); //false // true because 11+3=14
console.log( pairSum( [3,4,6,8,9,11], 8)  ); //false // false
console.log( pairSum( [3,4,4,8,9,11], 8)  ); //false // true because 4+4=8
console.log( pairSum( [3,4,6,8,9,11], 16) ); //false // false
console.log( pairSum( [3,4,6,8,9,11], 20) ); //false // true because 11+9=20
```

Comment: E onde está a pergunta?

Comment: Só de olhar por alto, esqueceste-te de um `=` aqui `if (i=j)` e os `for`'s estão incompletos pois falta-lhes `i++` e `j--`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function pairSum(target, number){
  for(var i in target){
    for(var j in target){
      if(i == j) continue;
      if(target[i] + target[j] == number) return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

console.log( pairSum( [3,4,6,8,9,11], 14) ); //true because 11+3=14
console.log( pairSum( [3,4,6,8,9,11], 8)  ); //false
console.log( pairSum( [3,4,4,8,9,11], 8)  ); //true because 4+4=8
console.log( pairSum( [3,4,6,8,9,11], 16) ); //false
console.log( pairSum( [3,4,6,8,9,11], 20) ); //true because 11+9=20
```

Comment: Isto não explica aonde está o problema, poderia editar e detalhar.

Answer (score 0):

Dois erros estavam complicando a solução do algoritmo:

```
if (i=j) {return false} else {
```

deveria ser:

```
if (i===j) {return false} else {
```

Isso faz com que o algoritmo avalie corretamente os casos positivos, mas se torne um loop infinito nos casos negativos. Isso pode ser facilmente corrigido transformando:

```
} else if (arr[i]+arr[j] < target) {
```

em:

```
} else if (arr[i]+arr[j] <= target) {
```

Código final, portanto, fica:

```
    function pairSum(arr, target){

    for (var i=0; i<arr.length;){

        for (var j = arr.length-1; j>=i;){

            if (i===j) {return false} else {

                if (arr[i] + arr[j] === target){ //we have our case

                    return true;

                } else if (arr[i]+arr[j] <= target) { //we don't have our case, but we know the last item (right index = j) needs to stay on the calculation, so we only change i

                    i++;

                } else {

                    j--; //we still don't have our case, but we know the last item (right index = j) is not part of the solution, so we skip it to the left, and we keep the left item (index = i)

                }
           }; 
        };

    };
    return false;

};

console.log( pairSum( [3,4,6,8,9,11], 14) ); //true 
console.log( pairSum( [3,4,6,8,9,11], 8)  ); //false 
console.log( pairSum( [3,4,4,8,9,11], 8)  ); //true 
console.log( pairSum( [3,4,6,8,9,11], 16) ); //false
console.log( pairSum( [3,4,6,8,9,11], 20) ); //true
```